# i have a shell script to generate release file but it is not working for me can some look into it

Tags: shell-script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

do_hash() {
    HASH_NAME=$1
    HASH_CMD=$2
    echo "${HASH_NAME}:"
    for f in $(find -type f); do
        f=$(echo $f | cut -c3-) # remove ./ prefix
        if [ "$f" = "Release" ]; then
            continue
        fi
        echo " $(${HASH_CMD} ${f}  | cut -d" " -f1) $(wc -c $f)"
    done
}

cat << EOF
Origin: Example Repository
Label: Example
Suite: stable
Codename: stable
Version: 1.0
Architectures: amd64 arm64 arm7
Components: main
Description: An example software repository
Date: $(date -Ru)
EOF
do_hash "MD5Sum" "md5sum"
do_hash "SHA1" "sha1sum"
do_hash "SHA256" "sha256sum"
```

in this above script am getting there is no Such file or directory at line No:16 error
after that it is failing like this but actually contains all the files and directories

```
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  8f7de0d9ea0d8b17d28bde898153b0b8 225 ./Release: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  7060eb1b50d13e3eb8d5c0e5319bf43f 456 ./main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  a23fbad7c8307a7c33abd897859c30bf 610 ./main/binary-amd64/Packages: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  383aec4711ae3f30b52cad172229e09876681c88 234 ./Release: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  b56b0bed2cac870a660bcdce72a6f1aa7706ac11 456 ./main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  152016c4f49b6bfc252559425c15039b2676bda2 610 ./main/binary-amd64/Packages: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  15779397e55fb2728b88e7e8a1b353774c0605704d60a6b7ea20e700c0ae9747 245 ./Release: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  2c8179e55703cb3251e4e2c01e6a0026c52787bd79c8f91e65b2ca94892daa3c 456 ./main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz: No such file or directory
../../../generate-release.sh: line 16:  6892a40e30918494a72057d684a0857324c17d4a744d5760882528d94a64a511 610 ./main/binary-amd64/Packages: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You could start with [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766) and [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.